# Pandas identify if for each date there is a date in previous year within a range of +- 15 days

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with all the customers sales for the last 4 years. I need to analyse for every customer that have purchased in the last 30 days if they have also purchased in previous years but within a range of +/- 15 days

The output should be the list of the customers with 2 additional columns (Prev Year, 2 Year ago) with a relevant Y if they have a purchase in previous year (2 years ago)

```
E.g.

Cust. Purchase

12345    10/20/16

12345    03/15/17

12345    11/15/17
```

Analysed sales:
Cust Purchase
12345    11/08/18

Result:

```
Cust Purchase. PY 2Year

12345    11/08/18  Y    N
```

I assume I need to loop all the last 30 days customers with a function but not sure how to write it

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I will go about it:

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO
import datetime as dt
```

Creating the dataframe:

```
s = StringIO('''Cust Purchase
12345 10/20/16
12345 03/15/17
12345 11/15/17 
''')

df = pd.read_csv(s, sep='\s+')
df.Purchase = pd.to_datetime(df.Purchase)
```

Function that does the job:

```
def test_prev_dates(date1, df=df,  year_back=1):
    for date2 in df.Purchase:
        if (date2.year == date1.year - year_back):
            date_temp = pd.to_datetime(f'{date1.year - 1}-{date1.month}-{date1.day}')
            date_lower = date_temp + dt.timedelta(days=-15)
            date_upper = date_temp + dt.timedelta(days=15)
            if (date2 >= date_lower) and (date2 <= date_upper):
                    return 'Y'
    return 'N'
```

You can obtain the desired output by looping over the customers:

```
test_prev_dates(pd.to_datetime("11/08/18"), df=df, year_back=1)
```

This returns `Y`

For two years back the call would be:

```
test_prev_dates(pd.to_datetime("11/08/18"), df=df, year_back=2)
```

which returns `N`

Hope this helps.